# MediaWiki with Twitter Boostrap using composer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mediawiki

I am having some difficulties implementing Twitter Bootstrap in my Mediawiki. I have installed it from Composer, but when I try to assign it to a variable like

```
$out = \bootstrap\BootstrapManager::getBootstrapManager();
```

It gives me an error, that it cannot be found. Am I missing something here?

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that's what you want to do. If you just want to complete installation, you need to add to your LocalSettings.php:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php";
```

If you really want to code something yourself, you can check the examples mentioned in the extension page, which [go something like](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-skins-chameleon/blob/359878dca3e163582db4640d67ec9f1d5ba1482f/Chameleon.php#L86)

```
    $setupAfterCache = new \Skins\Chameleon\Hooks\SetupAfterCache(
            \Bootstrap\BootstrapManager::getInstance(),
            $GLOBALS
```